# A matrix representation for the inverse matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a problem from *"Methods of Algebriac Geometry in Control Theory by Peter Falb"* textbook:

> Show that if $A$ is $\,n\times n\,$ matrix, then $\displaystyle\,(zI-A)^{-1} = \sum_{j=1}^n \phi_j\left(z\right) A^{n-j} \big/ \det\left[zI-A\right]$. Compute $\phi_j\left(z\right)$.

I am using the following formula:
$$
{\left(zI-A\right)}^{-1} = 
\frac{1}{\det \left(zI-A\right)}
\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\left(zI-A\right)^{s}
\sum_{k_1,k_2,\ldots ,k_{n-1}}
\prod_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{k_l+1}}{l^{k_l}\,k_{l}!}\,
\left(\operatorname{tr}\left(zI-A\right)^l\right)^{k_l}
$$ 
where the second summation is over $\displaystyle\,j+\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}lk_l=n-1$.
But I don't see how to find $\,\phi_j\left(z\right)$.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

P.S
In the book it's stated that $\phi_j(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-j$.

Comment: Here is one possible approach. Cayley-Hamilton theorem guarantees the inverse of a matrix $B$ is a polynomial in $B$ of degree at most $n-1$ . Therefore you can express $(zI-A)^{-1}$ as degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial in $A$. To find $\phi_j$, expand the left side of $(zI-A)\sum_{j=1}^n \phi_j(z) A^{n-j} = \det(zI-A)I$ and replace $A^n$ by a degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial in $A$ using Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Then compare coefficients on both sides. Note that $\phi_j$ may depend on $A$.

Comment: It looks like your formula already has an expression for $\phi(z)$? You're expecting something simpler?

Comment: @user7530 One would have to take OP's formula and rearrange things a bit to get the summands in the form $\phi_j(z)A^{n-j}$. (Given the complexity already involved, it's not much more work I guess.)

Comment: @user7530 I want to find $\phi_j(z)$ explicitly it's written that $\phi_j(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-j$.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Since trace is linear you should be able to extract some (not particularly pleasant) coefficients for the polynomial from your formula, after some mild manipulation.

Comment: @user7530 how do you suggest me to extract something meaningful from $tr((zI-A)^l)=tr(\sum_{k=0}^l { l\choose k}z^k A^{l-k})$?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist What you've written is $\sum_{k=0}^l \left[\binom{l}{k}\operatorname{tr}(A^{l-k})\right] z^k$.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist By the way, how do you know $\phi$ is supposed to be a polynomial in $z$? This is not stated in the question.

Comment: @user7530 it's stated in the book the question is taken from.

Comment: I'll add this fact in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit unclear as written -- from the notation one would infer that $\phi_j(z)$ is supposed to be independent of the matrix $A$, but this cannot be true; consider for instance $n=2$; set $z=0, A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right]$ to get that

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}-d & b\\c & -a\end{array}\right] = \phi_1(0) \left[\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right] + \phi_2(0) I$$
and no constants $\phi_j(0)$ can exist for which this equality holds for all $A$.

If $\phi_j$ is *not* required to be independent of $A$, then you already have your answer in the formula you posted, after some reindexing:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} (zI-A)^s f(s) &= \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^s \binom{s}{k} (-1)^k A^k z^{s-k} f(s)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{s=k}^{n-1} \binom{s}{k} (-1)^k A^k z^{s-k} f(s)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{s=n-j}^{n-1} \binom{s}{n-j} (-1)^{n-j} A^{n-j} z^{s-n+j} f(s)
\end{align*}

and 
$$\phi_j(z) = \sum_{s=n-j}^{n-1} \binom{s}{n-j} (-1)^{n-j} z^{s-n+j} f(s)$$
where $f(s)$ is your
$$\sum_{k_1,k_2,\ldots ,k_{n-1}}
\prod_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{k_l+1}}{l^{k_l}\,k_{l}!}\,
\left(\operatorname{tr}\left(zI-A\right)^l\right)^{k_l}.$$

Comment: How do you show that $\phi_j(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-j$?

Comment: Actually $f(s)$ has degree $n-1-s$, so $\phi_j$ would have degree $j-1$. Then again there is a stray $j$ in the "second summation" formula that I assumed was supposed to be an $s$; if that's not the case that may explain the discrepancy.